# How to serialize echo'd and error output in bash scripts

Tags: bash, echo, stdout, flush

An annoying problem I frequently have when writing shell scripts is that the output from echo statements shows up *after* the output of commands that come after the echo statements.

For example:

```
echo "step 1 -"
./step1

echo "step 2 -"
./step2

echo "step 3 -"
./step3
```

The output looks like this:

```
step1 output
step2 output
step3 output
step 1 -
step 2 - 
step 3 -
```

This defeats the purpose of those echo statements.  Is there any reasonably easy/convenient way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Redirect stderr from the commands to stdout so that output is serialized.

```
./step1 2>&1
```

Comment: Someone suggested a title edit, which brought this to my attention again, after almost 2 years. I'm pretty sure I didn't accept this answer because the output from the steps wasn't going to stderr, it was all going to stdout. But I don't see how that could be, now. I should've commented, and posted some proof of what I believed in the form of some actual test code and its output.